# OSX server 5.2 VPN type missing

Tags: macos, osx-server, vpn

OSX server 5.2 is supposed to have this drop-down menu "Configure VPN for"

but I don't have it.

I'm not able to select the type of VPN at all, I'm not sure why
 :  [image: Screenshot]

how can I have this option back?

Comment: I may be wrong, but I think in this version of macOS Server you determine the type of VPN connections available by how many addresses you assign to each type of VPN

Answer (score 1):

OS X Server 5.2 only supports L2TP/IPSec VPN.

Apple has dropped support for PPTP for security reasons. PPTP is known to have [a number of significant security vulnerabilities](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point-to-Point_Tunneling_Protocol#Security).

Apple started to warn their users in OS X El Capitan and iOS 9 during VPN client setup [not to use PPTP any more](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206152). With macOS Sierra and iOS 10, Apple has [removed PPTP client support](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT206844).

If, for some reason, despite of the security problems, you need to continue to use PPTP, you will probably need some third-party software. But you should not.